# An Inequality for a monotone function

Tags: functions, inequality, monotone-functions

I am working on a problem where I am dealing with a function $g$ that is monotone with increasing differences, i.e., $g(x+1)\ge g(x)$ and $g(x+2)-g(x+1) \ge g(x+1)-g(x)$. I have four numbers $p_1,q_1,p_2,q_2 \in [0,1]$ and denote by $\widetilde{t}$ the value $1-t$.

I am trying to see if I can establish the non-negativity of the below term $T(x)$.

\begin{align*}
\bigg[p_2\left[ q_2 \left(g(x+2) - g(x+1) \right) + \widetilde{q}_2 \left( g(x+1) - g(x) \right) \right] 
+
\widetilde{p}_2\left[ q_2 \left(g(x+3) - g(x+2) \right) + \widetilde{q}_2 \left( g(x+2) - g(x+1) \right) \right]\bigg] \\
- \\
\bigg[p_1\left[ q_1 \left(g(x+1) - g(x) \right) + \widetilde{q}_1 \left( g(x) - g(x-1) \right) \right] 
+
\widetilde{p}_1\left[ q_1 \left(g(x+2) - g(x+1) \right) + \widetilde{q}_1 \left( g(x+1) - g(x) \right) \right]\bigg]
\end{align*}
Using the above two properties of $g$, I can show that $T(x)$ is non-negative when either $q_2\ge q_1$ or $\widetilde{p}_2 \ge \widetilde{p}_1$. Is it possible to show that the inequality holds true when "$q_2 < q_1$ and $\widetilde{p}_2 < \widetilde{p}_1$" (perhaps under some conditions if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample on $\Bbb R_+$:
$$g(x)=x^2,\quad p_1=0,\quad p_2=1,\quad q_2=0,\quad q_1=1.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Interestingly, I also just came up with this counter-example on a graphing calculator. Do you think there is a way to establish this inequality "under certain sufficient conditions"?

Comment: No idea. To find this counter-example, I first noticed that the whole problem is about the sequence $a_n=g(x+n)$ for a fixed $x$, and that the hypothesis is equivalent to the sequence $b_n:=a_{n+1}-a_n$ being non-decreasing and non-negative. Then, $T(x)\ge0$ for all $p_1,p_2\in[0,1]$ (and $q_1,q_2$ fixed) is equivalent to... (sorry I have to leave in a hurry, I'll be back in some hours)

Comment: ...equivalent to $[\bar q_2b_0+q_2b_1,\bar q_2b_1+q_2b_2]\ge[\bar q_1b_{-1}+q_1b_0,\bar q_1b_0+q_1b_1].$ It was then easy, given $0<b_{-1}<b_0<b_1<b_2,$ to choose $q_1,q_2$ such that these two segments overlap.